# Same address but different string

Tags: c++, nan, v8

Below results show two same string pointer have different value.

Why?

v8::String::Utf8Value just gives its string member, see https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d4/da0/v8_8h_source.html#l01286

```cpp
#include <nan.h>
#include <string>

NAN_METHOD(Print) {
    Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::String> maybeString = Nan::To<v8::String>(info[0]);
    if (maybeString.IsEmpty() == false) {
        v8::Local<v8::String> str = maybeString.ToLocalChecked();
        char *ptr = *v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), str);
        printf("string %s\n", *v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), str));
        printf("       %s\n", ptr);
        printf("ptr %p\n", *v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), str));
        printf("    %p\n", ptr);
        printf("ptr %p\n", (char *)*v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), str));
        printf("    %p\n", (char *)ptr);
        printf("string %s\n", (char *)*v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), str));
        printf("       %s\n", (char *)ptr);
    }
}

NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init) {  
    Nan::Set(target, Nan::New("print").ToLocalChecked(),
        Nan::GetFunction(Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Print)).ToLocalChecked());
}

NODE_MODULE(myaddon, Init);
```

Result of `info[0]='hello world'`:

```
string hello world
       �AZ
ptr 0x65a4140
    0x65a4140
ptr 0x65a4140
    0x65a4140
string hello world
       �AZ
```

Comment: Usually that happens when the object you're pointing to is destroyed, so the pointer isn't pointing to the same data anymore.  This can happen if you return a pointer to a local variable in a function.

Answer (score 5):

```
    printf("string %s\n", *v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), str));
```

Here, you create a new object of type `v8::String::Utf8Value`. It's a temporary object. As soon as this statement completes, it will no longer exist. This is fine, but this is not:

```
    char *ptr = *v8::String::Utf8Value(info.GetIsolate(), str);
    printf("       %s\n", ptr);
```

After the first line of code executes, the `v8::String::Utf8Value` no longer exists. So the `ptr` doesn't point to anything. (If you think it does, explain how you would free the memory it points to.) So you can't access it later, but your `printf` does.